# Given a measure space $ \ ( \Omega, \Sigma, \mu) $ and a sequence $ A_n \in{} \Sigma $ Demonstrate that

Tags: real-analysis

Guys can someone help me with this demo?
Given a measure space $ \ ( \Omega , \Sigma , \mu ) $ and a sequence $A_n \in{} \Sigma $
Prove that: $ \mu
\ ( \displaystyle\cup{}_{n=1}^{ \infty }A_n ) \leq{} \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }
\mu \ ( A_n ) $

$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k\right)\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(A_k)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then I can use the fact that $\mu $ is a measure so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k\right )=\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty }A_k\right)$. it is right? any way to demonstrate it better?

Answer (score 3):

Define inductively
$$ B_1 := A_1\quad\text{and}\quad B_n := A_n \setminus \bigcup _{k=1}^{n-1}A_k,\quad n\geqslant 2.$$
It holds that $\bigcup _{k=1}^{\infty} A_k = \bigcup _{k=1}^{\infty} B_k$. The $B_k$ are pairwise disjoint and $B_k\subseteq A_k$ for all $k$.
Consequently,
$$\mu \left ( \bigcup _{k=1}^\infty A_k \right ) = \mu \left ( \bigcup _{k=1}^\infty B_k \right ) = \sum _{k=1}^\infty \mu (B_k) \leqslant \sum _{k=1}^\infty \mu (A_k).$$

---

To make your approach work note that
$$ C_n :=\bigcup _{k=1}^n A_k \nearrow \bigcup _{k=1}^\infty A_k =: C. $$
Since $\mu$ is continuous from below we have $\mu (C_n) \to \mu (C)$. Hence, from finite subadditivity
$$ \mu \left ( \bigcup _{k=1}^\infty A_k \right ) = \lim _{n\to\infty} \mu \left ( \bigcup _{k=1}^n A_k \right ) \leqslant \lim _{n\to\infty} \sum _{k=1}^n \mu (A_k) = \sum _{k=1}^\infty \mu (A_k). $$

Comment: I think OP is invoking measure continuity (in particular continuity 'from below'), and their 'mistake' is not going into details.

Comment: @Snoop Yeah, it seems so, I got tunnelvisioned - have had some of my students try to argue countable subadditivity (and not using $\sigma$-additivity) by induction or something like that which doesn't work.